# Setting alarm in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my application Application_Exit event i am trying to set an alarm using the ScheduledActionService. This works fine in other code but here it keeps throwing an argumentexception with message E_INVALIDARG

Here's the code

```
 string alarmName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 const string cookingClockAlarm = "Cooking clock alarm";
 DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
 var alarm = new Alarm(alarmName)
                    {
                        Content = cookingClockAlarm,
                        BeginTime = dueTime,
                        ExpirationTime = dueTime.AddSeconds(3),
                        RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None
                    };
 // Register the alarm with the system.
 ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);//here I get an exception
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Interesting, I had the same issue with calls to ScheduledActionService.Find that occurred as the app was shutting down. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510152/scheduledactionservice-find-throws-argumentexception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this code in the `Application_Closing` method and it didn't throw an error. Seems like in the Exit event it is too late to do schedule an alarm.