# ScheduledActionService.Find throws ArgumentException

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 app deployed in the marketplace that updates its Live Tile via a PeriodicTask Background Agent.

One user is reporting issues with the tile no longer updating after it has been working for some time.

When they check the background tasks on the phone it is disabled and the checkbox to "Turn background tasks back on for this application the next time I open it" is checked.

After opening the app and trying the pin operation again the background task hasn't resumed.

I suspect this may be related to two crash reports I've seen in the App Hub:

> Problem Function: Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.CheckHr
>
> Exception Type: ArgumentException
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> Frame    Image             Function                                                                   Offset
> 0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                                         19
> 1        mscoree3_7.dll    WatsonUnhandledManagedException                                            296
> 2        mscoree3_7.dll    Dbg_NotifyManagedException                                                 93
> 3        mscoree3_7.dll    FirstPassException                                                         1044
> 4                          TransitionStub                                                             0
> 5                          Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.CheckHr                248
> 6                          Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.GetNotificationByID    156
> 7                          **Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService.Find**                      276
> 8                          MyApp.Agents.TaskIsActive                                        60
> 9                          MyApp.MainPage.SetupApplicationBar                               44
> 10                         MyApp.MainPage.MainPage_Loaded                                   100
> 11                         MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler                           3660
> 12                         MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent                                           1348
> 13       mscoree3_7.dll    IL_CallManaged                                                             884
> 14       mscoree3_7.dll    IL_CallDelegateInternal                                                    176
> 15       mscoree3_7.dll    makeComPlusCall                                                            5255
> 16       mscoree3_7.dll    makeComPlusCallReturnInt                                                   21
> 17                                                                                                    0
> 18       agcore.dll        CCoreServices::CLR_FireEvent                                               385

Calls to Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService.Find are resulting in an ArgumentException.

The name parameter I am calling the Find method with is coming from a `private const string` so the value will be the same with each call.

Should I just catch this exception and assume the background agent isn't present or is it indicating something is wrong with the agent?

At this stage I can't reproduce the exception when running the app in the emulator.

---

> "When [the] Background Agent crashes two times in sequence, it's removed from scheduling"

I've tried deliberately crashing the ScheduledAgent on every invocation as follows:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    UpdateTile();

#if DEBUG
    // If we're debugging, fire the task again
    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest("MyScheduledTaskAgent", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
    throw new Exception("Bang");
#endif

     NotifyComplete();
}
```

This does cause the background task to turn off under the settings in the emulator after two invocations. However, if I reopen the app calls to ScheduledActionService.Find work without an exception. I can also remove the failed PeriodicTask and add a new instance without issue.

---

> "an exception can be thrown when the background agent is deactivated in the phone's settings. I think in that case the exception is thrown on ScheduledActionService.Add, not ScheduledActionService.Find"

I tried this in the emulator. I get the following exception from `ScheduledActionService.Add(task);`:

System.InvalidOperationException - "BNS Error: The action is disabled\r\n"

Calls to ScheduledActionService.Find still work fine.

Comment: "At this stage I can't reproduce the exception when running the app in the emulator." I know an exception can be thrown when the background agent is deactivated in the phone's settings. I think in that case the exception is thrown on `ScheduledActionService.Add`, not `ScheduledActionService.Find`, but you should give it a try.

Comment: When `Background Agent` crashes two times in sequence, it's removed from scheduling. Maybe some exceptions are throwns here that cause this behavior...

Comment: @Ku6opr, thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that and updated the question with the results. It doesn't appear to be the cause.

Comment: @KooKiz, Thanks. I gave that a try. As you suggested, this caused an InvalidOperationException from the `ScheduledActionService.Add` method but `.Find` was unaffected.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, the exception could be raised from the .Add method not the .Find from my experience with BGs, you have to surround your Add method with a try catch block.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution for this behavior? My users report the exact same thing, and the stack trace a have is the same

Comment: @TomášBezouška nothing definite as yet. Any day now I'm my latest [update](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=a93003ca-fc23-45bc-92df-82adc23d1597) should reach the marketplace. In it I've wrapped the call to ScheduledActionService.Find in a try catch. Hopefully that will provide me with some more details about when it is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the ArgumentException and StackTrace in the emulator and on a handset attached to my PC.

The steps were:

1. Set a break point in an exception handler around the call to `ScheduledActionService.Find(TASK_NAME)`
2. Start the app up in the emulator (or handset) with the debugger attached
3. Use the pin menu item to start the PeriodicTask background agent. Note that in debug mode I call `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(TASK_NAME, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));` immediately after adding the PeriodicTask.
4. Navigate to a sub page in my app.
5. Quickly use the back button to return to the MainPage and then again to quit the applicaiton. The Loaded event on the MainPage calls `SetupApplicationBar()`, which ultimately calls the `ScheduledActionService.Find()` method.
6. As the application is shutting down the exception will occur.

> Exception Type: ArgumentException
>
> Message: E_INVALIDARG
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.CheckHr(Int32 hr)
> at Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.GetNotificationByID(Guid notificationID)
> at Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService.Find(String name)
> at SolarCalculator.Agents.TaskIsActive()
> at SolarCalculator.MainPage.SetupApplicationBar()
> at SolarCalculator.MainPage.MainPage_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
> at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)

Given that the app is shutting down and I'm only trying to figure out if the background agent is running I figure it is safe to catch the exception and return false from my `TaskIsActive()` method.

Now that I know the message from the ArgumentException is E_INVALIDARG I found [Setting alarm in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630168/setting-alarm-in-windows-phone-7) which describes getting the same error when making calls to ScheduleActionService in the Application_Exit event.

Comment: I've seen a similar crash stack:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/106202/625836.aspx#625836