# Windows phone: using periodic agent

Tags: c#, windows-phone, background-agents, periodic-task

I have an Windows Phone markeplace app. Users reports that app sometimes crashes at Windows Phone 8. Here is my data from windows phone dev center report:

Problem funciton:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.CheckHr
```

Exception type

```
system.reflection.targetinvocationexception
```

Stack trace:

```
Frame    Image                 Function                                                                  Offset        
0        microsoft_phone_ni    Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.CheckHr               0x0000019a    
1        microsoft_phone_ni    Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.SystemNotificationInterop.CreateNotification    0x0000002e    
2        microsoft_phone_ni    Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService.Add                      0x00000056    
3        myapp_ni              Myapp.MainPage..ctor                                                      0x000000b0
```

Problem can be with background agent. I have used [these tutorial](http://wildermuth.com/2011/09/06/Periodic_Agents_on_Windows_Phone_7_1).

My code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        /* Periodic agents*/
            // A unique name for your task. It is used to  
            // locate it in from the service. 
            var taskName = "MyTask";

            // If the task exists 
            var oldTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(taskName) as PeriodicTask;
            if (oldTask != null)
            {
                ScheduledActionService.Remove(taskName);
            }

            // Create the Task 
            PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask(taskName);

            // Description is required 
            task.Description = "This saves some data to Isolated Storage";

            // Add it to the service to execute 
            ScheduledActionService.Add(task);

          /* Testing my agent*/
         //   ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(taskName, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));
           /* Testing my agent*/

        /* Periodic agents */
...
```

I readed [ScheduledActionService.Find throws ArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510152/scheduledactionservice-find-throws-argumentexception), but didn't got idea behind it

Answer (score 0):

You must put your periodic agent code in App.xaml.cs inside method on `Application_Closing`